# Can't connect to device on separate AP

Tags: networking, connection, wireless-access-point, curl

Short version: If I am connected to my main router and the other device is connected to a secondary AP (connected to the main router/modem with an Ethernet cable), I am unable to connect to the device. But if I am on either of the two APs at the same time as the other device then I can connect without a problem.

Long version: I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a Wi-Fi extender (using Wi-Fi); the Wi-Fi extender is connected via Ethernet cable to the main router/modem. I also have another device (NodeMCU) connected to the main router via Wi-Fi. 
Now, when I am SSH'd into the raspberry Pi, I try to make a curl request to the NodeMCU but get no response whatsoever, not even if I simply try to ping the device. However, if I am to move the NodeMCU so that it will connect with the same Wi-Fi extender as the raspberry Pi is connected to, I can connect just fine. The issue is that I need the two devices to be in those seperate physical locations meaning that I am stuck trying to work out how to make the two devices contact each other.

I understand that the issue is most likely with the settings on the Wi-Fi extender. However, the problem is that I admittedly do not know a lot about networking at this level. Therefore, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out! Is there some sort of setting I can change in the Wi-Fi extender to fix this? DHCP for example? (I tried simply disabling the DHCP Client but that didn't seem to work). Or is there some way I can adapt the curl command to force it to go through the main access point so that it reaches the NodeMCU?

Thank you in advance for any help,

Kind regards,
Tom

P.S. To cut short: due to compatibility issues with what I am running on the Raspberry Pi, I am unable to simply connect that straight into the main router with an Ethernet cable.